# jquery hover on all divs not just parent

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I am trying to add a border on any div that i hover. So when i hover on a certain div with a class i add a class that has the div.

But if i have a parent div and some inner divs, when i go to hover on the inner divs, its on putting a border on the parent div.

Is there a way to sort this so when i hover on the inner divs that it adds the border

here is a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/XCcYm/

JS :

```
$('.columnP, .nameP').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('pi-edit-row');
});
$('.pi-edit-row').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('pi-edit-row-now');
    $(this).append('<div class="edit">edit</div>');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('pi-edit-row-now');
    $(this).find('.edit').remove();
});
```

HTML :

```
<div class="columnP">
    <div class="nameP">Awesome</div>
    <p>Blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand, you want to add a BORDER to any div you hover over? why not use :hover css?

Answer (score 0):

Use mouseover instead of hover

```
 $('.pi-edit-row').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('pi-edit-row-now');
    $(this).append('<div class="edit">edit</div>');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('pi-edit-row-now');
    $(this).find('.edit').remove();
});
```

**Updated**

```
$('.pi-edit-row').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).find(".pi-edit-row").addClass('pi-edit-row-now');
        $(this).find(".pi-edit-row").append('<div class="edit">edit</div>');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find(".pi-edit-row").removeClass('pi-edit-row-now');
        $(this)find('.edit').remove();
    });
```